# Is the Samsung S27E330 a good monitor choice for me?

Tags: monitors

I am a programmer and next week I will start working from home.  My desk will be shared by my work computer, my desktop, and my personal laptop sometimes.

I am considering the Samsung S27E330.  I haven't seen many recent laptops without both VGA and HDMI, so the work laptop should be fine to plug in.  The desktop has HDMI and DVI, so I can get it to work pretty well.

Will the monitor being a "gaming" monitor cause any problems with performance or quality while working?  I would be using Visual Studio, SSMS, and SSRS when working from home.  I may also setup as dualscreen with my old monitor from time to time.

My desktop has an ATI HD7700.  I use this computer for gaming and photo editing.
My personal laptop is a Lenovo W520 with the two cards. Used for work, internet.
I haven't gotten my work laptop yet, but I imagine it will be pretty new.

Comment: My impression is that the label "gaming" on a monitor is to indicate that the monitor has sufficient performance for First Person Shooter and similar fast paced games with a low Response Time and good colors and sometimes with a Refresh Rate greater than 60Hz. Looking at the Samsung web site that looks to be a good display http://www.samsung.com/uk/business/business-products/business-monitor/essential/LS27E330HSX/EN and better than the 22" Lenovo's I use. I have two though and you may want to consider having two yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think I will order this one and probably a second in the future.

Comment: I took another look at the tech specs and clicked on the show more specs to see what interfaces are provided. The page says D-Sub and HDMI and there is no Display Port or DVI. Check your laptop. Most laptops that I see have HDMI and/or D-Sub with VGA.